Running notebook in the background on a billion-row data kept on crashing
I have a notebook that tests out different settings of Connectorx on a dataset with over one billion rows. The code I use to run it on the server is as follows:
nohup jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute ../notebooks/bg.ipynb --inplace &

The issue is whenever I run this notebook CPU% will be above 200% causing the server to crash. Is there a way to run the notebook without crashing the server? I tried to set:
On command line
n_cpu=4
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=$n_cpu
export MKL_NUM_THREADS=$n_cpu
export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=$n_cpu
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$n_cpu

On the notebook
import os
n_cpu=4
os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = str(n_cpu)
os.environ['MKL_NUM_THREADS'] = str(n_cpu)
os.environ['NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS'] = str(n_cpu)
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = str(n_cpu)

None of those worked.
